# Eager load extra model attributes

Tags: php, oop, laravel, eloquent

**I am using Eloquent with Laravel.**

The case: I'm building an API where there is possibility to `include` relations for a Resource. So for example `/api/teams?include=users` will add the `User` model for every `Team`. For the logic that includes the relationship I'm using [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/). So I need to have some logic that determines which relationship has to be included, so I can create a optimized query for it.

Problem: When I want to render a collection of a `Team` with the related `User` models. I can eager-load the models just fine. The problems comes when I have custom attributes on the `User` model. These will cause a N+1 query problem because for every eager-loaded team, because the query for the custom attributes will be executed for every model.

**Example code:**

```
// The Team model with the custom attribute
class Team extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['is_member'];

    public function getIsMemberAttribute() {
        $loggedUser = Auth::currentUser();

        $result = DB::table('team_user')
                        ->where('team_id', $this-id)
                        ->where('user_id', $loggedUser->id)
                        ->get();

        return !is_null($result);
    }
}

// The controller code
$team = Team::findOrFail($teamId);

// So this will return all the User models that belong to the Team.
// The problem is this will execute the query inside the getIsMemberAttribute() for every User model.
dd($team->users);
```

Is there a good pattern to solve this issue?

Comment: Provide some code. That would help

Comment: @JilsonThomas added some code ;)!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the User models and see if one of them matches the logged in user. It's more efficient than looking it up in the database.

```
class Team extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['is_member'];

    public function getIsMemberAttribute() {
        $loggedUser = Auth::currentUser();

        foreach ($this->users as $user) {

            if ($user->id == $loggedUser->id) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```